# Exclude users who already received an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query

I'm trying to send an email and exclude the users who already received it yesterday using the same data extension. The code provided by Salesforce help is this:

```sql
SELECT su.EmailAddress as Emailaddress, su.SubscriberKey 
FROM _Sent se WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN _Bounce b WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON se.JobID = b.JobID
        AND se.ListID = b.ListID
        AND se.BatchID = b.BatchID
        AND se.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID
    JOIN _Subscribers se WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON su.SubscriberID = se.SubscriberID
WHERE s.JobID = 581642
AND b.JobID IS NULL
```

I have already replaced the job ID as the instructions on the help page stated, but I am getting the error:

> **The query syntax is invalid**
>   The correlation name 'se' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong here, I am ready to bang my head against the wall I don't understand SQL.

Comment: I can see you have used _Subscribers se, looks like that is causing an issue. Please try removing and then execute.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so other users can easily see that this answer is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you used `se` for the `_Sent` and `_Subscribers` dataextension in your query. Furthermore you used `s` for the WHERE-condition checking the JobID, which should be `se` instead I guess.

**So this should work:**

```sql
SELECT su.EmailAddress as Emailaddress, su.SubscriberKey 
FROM _Sent se WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN _Bounce b WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON se.JobID = b.JobID
        AND se.ListID = b.ListID
        AND se.BatchID = b.BatchID
        AND se.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID
    JOIN _Subscribers su WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON su.SubscriberID = se.SubscriberID
WHERE se.JobID = 581642
AND b.JobID IS NULL
```